# Mouse changes object

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am working on a game (c# and xna game studio 4.0) which is familiar to Mario. I want to make object change color when the mouse us on the object.

Will something like

```
If(Mouse.Intersects.(object)) {}
```

work

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out :)?
Or are you asking how to detect a mouse click over a given object?

Comment: I am asking how to detect if the place where the mouse is is on n object

Comment: Is this a 3D game or a 2D one? You mention Mario but there are 3D Mario games

Comment: It is a 2D! It is my first game on xna so still not 3d.

Comment: In other words how can I detect the .X and .Y variables of the mouse

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7911159/2830652):

```
MouseState current_mouse = Mouse.GetState();
Vector2 pos = new Vector2(current_mouse.X, current_mouse.Y);
```

Allows you to detect your mouse position. You'll then need to figure out what that means in world coordinates, which'll depend on the way you've implemented your camera.